# how to find multiple PID of same script

Tags: python, cross-platform

```
$ ps aux | grep file1.py
xyz    6103  0.0  0.1  33476  6480 pts/1    S+   12:00   0:00 python file1.py
xyz    6188  0.0  0.1  33476  6472 pts/2    S+   12:05   0:00 python file1.py
xyz    7294  0.0  0.0   8956   872 pts/4    S+   12:49   0:00 grep --color=auto file1.py
```

process 6103 has started at 12:00 and after 5 minutes process 6188 started. I need to find out both the processes 6103,6188

## pid_finder.py

```
import psutil

PROCNAME = "file1.py"

process = []
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    if proc.name == PROCNAME:
        print proc
```

But the above script printed out nothing. can "psutil" module have other option to find pid of the process of a script.

psutil.test() gave following o/p...

```
xyz      6103  0.0  0.2   33476    6480 /dev/pts/1    13:23   30:00  python
xyz      6188  0.0  0.2   33476    6480 /dev/pts/2    13:23   30:00  python
xyz      8831  0.0  1.0  430612   39796 ?             13:31   30:03  gedit
xyz      8833  0.0    ?   14540     808 ?             13:31   30:00  gnome-pty-helper
xyz      8835  0.0  0.1   23636    5008 /dev/pts/5    13:31   30:00  bash
xyz      9367  0.0  0.2   51580    7740 /dev/pts/4    13:42   30:00  python
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: you should also include `grep -v grep` in your command to eliminate the grep line

Comment: I've tried "ps aux | grep file1.py"

Comment: `PROCNAME` is not `file1.py` but rather `python` and `file1.py` is the first argument to the interpreter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like this, if you are not worried of the **os.popen()**

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
PROCNAME = "file1.py"
pids = []
for proc_data in os.popen('/bin/ps -eo pid,comm,args'):
    bits = proc_data.strip().split()
    (pid, comm ) = bits[0:2]
    args = " ".join( bits[3:] )
    if args == PROCNAME:
        pids.append( pid )

print pids
```

This should let you find things base on the args of the process.

You could change it so that comm and args where the one string if required.

```
    pid = bits[0]
    comm_and_args = " ".join( bits[1:] )
```

Answer (score 0):

please read up on `pidof`:

```
man pidof
```